# Symfony 4, check if template is already loaded?

Tags: php, symfony

I have a template `home.html.twig` loaded and an ajax request as the code below shows. That works just fine.

But if I load my website with the route `mywebsite.com/search/foo` then I only have `searchListing.html.twig` displayed without any `home.html.twig` loaded so the site is broken

So is there a way in the controller, before the return, to check if my template `home.html.twig` is loaded and if not load it and insert `searchListing.html.twig` inside a block ?

my html:

`<li><a href="{{ path('search', {var: 'foo'}) }}" class="trigger">foo</a></li>`

here is my ajax:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.trigger').on('click', function(e) {

      e.preventDefault();
      const $link = $(e.currentTarget);

      $.ajax({
        url: $link.attr('href'),
        type: 'get'
      })
      .done(function (data) {
        $('#main-content').html(data)
      })
  });

});
```

my controller:

```
class Search extends AbstractController {

  /**
  * @Route("/search/{var}", name="search")
  */

  public function search ($var) {

    // CHECK HERE
    // if home.html.twig is loaded > load searchListing.html.twig inside a given block
    // if home.html.twig is not loaded > load home.html.twig then load searchListing.html.twig inside a given block

    return $this->render('searchListing.html.twig',[
      'var' => $var,
    ]);

  }

}
```

Comment: You can check if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest()) to check is ajax request and load home_page.html.twig.

Comment: That works only if the client sends the `X_REQUESTED_WITH: XMLHttpRequest` header though. Works with jQuery out of the box, won't work with Angular out of the box. Better approach would be to send an additional flag like `withoutLayout=1` and return partial response in the controller then. There's no magic involved and the result is much more verbose and clean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly you need:

```
/**
 * @Route("/search/{var}", name="search")
 */
public function search (Request $request, $var) {

    // render only search results for ajax request
    if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
        return $this->render('searchListing.html.twig',[
            'var' => $var,
        ]);
    }

    return $this->render('home.html.twig',[
        'var' => $var,
    ]);

}
```

Comment: That works only if the client sends the `X_REQUESTED_WITH: XMLHttpRequest` header though. Works with jQuery out of the box, won't work with Angular out of the box. Better approach would be to send an additional flag like `withoutLayout=1` and return partial response in the controller then. There's no magic involved and the result is much more verbose and clean.

Comment: It works but that is the opposite way, instead of checking if the template is loaded, you check if this is an Ajax request then load one template or the other.

Comment: What do you mean by: `checking if the template is loaded` ?

Comment: @KamilAdryjanek I mean check if `home.html.twig` is actually displayed. if it is just load `listing` into it; if not load `home` then load `listing` inside the home block

Comment: How do you include `searchListing.html.twig` in `home.html.twig`?

Comment: inside `searchListing.html.twig`  I have:  `{% extends 'home.html.twig' %}` then `{% block content %}code{% endblock %}`

Comment: btw that does not work well because all my dependencies have the wrong url: ie my css is url `search/css/style.css` instead of `css/style.css`

Comment: I accepted your answer since it solves the issue. I also fixed my css using `{{asset() }}` tags. last problem with your technique is that I need to have the `{% extends 'home.html.twig' %}` only without ajax otherwise there is no ajax benefit since Im reloading everything all the time